# How did printf handle this char** parameter?

Tags: c, string, parsing, reference, printf

I am writing an assembler in C and fixed a bug in my parser (*see below for parser function definition and input file*). The output from my program was ...

```
-bash-3.2$ ./a.out branch.asm out.obj
input file name = 'branch.asm'
output file name = 'out.obj'


Error, couldn't find an opcode in token sequence: '▒▒▒▒mul' 'r0' ...
-bash-3.2$
```

I realize that my when I pass char** pLabel to printf I need to dereference it. What I don't understand is: How was printf able to still print the string even though I gave it a bad parameter? And if it is still able to find the string, why prefix it with garbage (I assume the garbage comes from the string address value)?

Let me know if you would like me to include more information. It's just a large program and I didn't feel that the rest of the source is necessary to understanding my question (which really just revolves around how printf handles string references).

INPUT FILE FOLLOWS ...

```
        .ORIG x3000
LABEL1  AND R0,R0,#0
        ADD R0,R1,R2            ;
LABEL2  ADD R0,R0,#-1           ;
        BRP LABEL2
        BRNZ    label
        BRNZ    LABEL1
        BRNZP   LABEL1
        BR      LABEL1
LABEL   BRP     LABEL1
MUL     R0,R1,R2                ;
        .END
```

END OF INPUT FILE
START OF PARSER DEFINITION ...

```
/* Input: Assembly Program Input File
          Pointer to current assembly line
   Work:  attaches pointer vars to strings holding the
          LABEL, Opcode, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, and Arg4
   Ret:   EMPTY_LINE,   (Line was empty)
          OK,           (Line is now parsed)
          DONE          (No more lines in File)
   Note:  Pseudo-ops are returned as Opcodes.
*/
int readAndParse( FILE * pInfile, char * pLine, char ** pLabel, char ** pOpcode,
                  char ** pArg1, char ** pArg2, char ** pArg3, char ** pArg4)
{
  char * lRet, * lPtr;
  int i;
  /* Pull line (INCLUDING \n) and return in pLine string */
  if( !fgets( pLine, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, pInfile ) )  return( DONE );

  for( i = 0; i < strlen( pLine ); i++ ) /* Convert entire line to lowercase  */
    pLine[i] = tolower( pLine[i] );

  *pLabel = *pOpcode = *pArg1 = *pArg2 = *pArg3 = *pArg4 = pLine + strlen(pLine); /* Point to '\0'! */

  /* ignore the assembly comments ... */
  lPtr = pLine;
  while( *lPtr != ';' && *lPtr != '\0' && *lPtr != '\n' )
    lPtr++; /* Find the 1st occurence of comment or a newline */

  *lPtr = '\0'; /* Chunck any comments or newlines. We only want relevant tokens. */

  /* Fetch first token in pLine delimted by \t \n (SPACE) or ,. strtok returns NULL when \0.
     Subsequent calls expect the a parameter of NULL & continue where it left off.
  */
  if( !(lPtr = strtok( pLine, "\t\n ," ) ) )  return( EMPTY_LINE );

  /* Logic to handle option of LABEL vs Opcode as starting token for line */
  if( isOpcode( lPtr ) == -1 && lPtr[0] != '.' ) /* found a label */
  {
    *pLabel = lPtr;
    if( !( lPtr = strtok( NULL, "\t\n ," ) ) ) return( OK );
  }
  *pOpcode = lPtr;
  if( isOpcode( *pOpcode ) == -1 && lPtr[0] != '.' )
    {
      printf("\nError, couldn't find an opcode in token sequence: '%s' '%s' ...\n", pLabel, *pOpcode);
      exit(2);
    }

  if( !( lPtr = strtok( NULL, "\t\n ," ) ) ) return( OK );
  *pArg1 = lPtr;

  if( !( lPtr = strtok( NULL, "\t\n ," ) ) ) return( OK );
  *pArg2 = lPtr;

  if( !( lPtr = strtok( NULL, "\t\n ," ) ) ) return( OK );
  *pArg3 = lPtr;

  if( !( lPtr = strtok( NULL, "\t\n ," ) ) ) return( OK );
  *pArg4 = lPtr;

  return( OK );
}
```

Comment: Oh, by the way, MUL is not a valid opcode in this (16-bit) ISA if you were wondering ...

Comment: The question and the shown code doesn't really go well with each other... Anyways `printf()` with `%s` format specifier looks up the memory location which is passed as the argument and prints out the characters util it finds a null terminator..

Comment: The behavior I got from the posted code is what prompted my question; maybe you mean I gave you too much unnecessary information? Also, I understand printf prints until it reaches a null terminator. What I want to know is how did the junk get in there preceding the string I had intended to print.

Comment: Yes please be precise what your problem is ?? This is too much information..!!

Comment: A detailed walk through of how printf handled the char** would satisfy my curiosity ...

Comment: From this code, it doesn't appear that `printf` is ever given a `char**`.

Comment: It's right under the 5th if statement from the bottom. char** pLabel is a readAndParse parameter that gets passed into printf.

Comment: if( isOpcode( *pOpcode ) == -1 && lPtr[0] != '.' )
    {
      printf("\nError, couldn't find an opcode in token sequence: '%s' '%s' ...\n", pLabel, *pOpcode);
      exit(2);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened is the following: in the memory layout *pLabel is followed by the characters pointed to by pLine.
In the call to printf, where pLabel is not dereferenced, printf finds at pLabel four non-zero bytes and prints them (this is actually the address stored in pLabel). Because printf did not see a terminating null character, it continues printing bytes found following pLabel, which is pLine. pLine starts with 'mul' followed by the \0 put there by strtok.

Comment: Thanks Paul! That's what I was looking for. Now the only thing that still has me is that what I wanted was the string *pLabel = mul\0 printed,  so when I print it's address pLabel by mistake, why should the contents of that address (i.e., mul\0 ) immediately follow the address as print is incrementing and searching for the null termination? Does this have to do with how the stack is organized when printf is called? Thanks again.

Comment: @Michael, yes, this can have to do with the stack or with the global memory. In your code I cannot see how the function is called or where the parameters are stored. If I could see that, I could explain more precise. Now all I can conclude is that in memory pLine follows pLabel.